# bootstrap carousel caption is hiding on mobile screen if screen size is <= 4 inch

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, slider, carousel, caption

Hi Friends i am using bootstrap 3 carousal. I am facing once problem in mobile when the mobile screen is <=4 inch. My slider's caption is hiding half on left side on the smaller screen. please help.

Code:

```
 <div id="kc1" class="carousel " data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators hidden-xs">
 <li data-target="#kc1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
 <li data-target="#kc1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
 </ol>
 <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">         
 <div class="item active" id="websites">
 <a href="websites-systems-trainings.php"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/full-responsive-websites-system-solutions1.jpg";text="Slide+0" alt="Slide 0"></a>
 <div class="carousel-caption img-rounded featurette-heading text-center col-md-offset-1 opa1 onee1"  style="background-color:#004080;">
 <h1 style="font-size:25px;">This is test example and half caption is hiding in left side on mobile device below <=4 inch screen </h1> 
 <h6>
 <a href="websites-systems-trainings.php" class="btn-default btn-sm">More</a> 
 </h6>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="item" id="SEO-SEM">
 <a href="seo-sem-ppc.php"> <img class="img-responsive" src="img/seo-sem.jpg";text="Slide+1" alt="Slide 1"></a>
 <div class="carousel-caption img-rounded featurette-heading text-center col-md-offset-2"  style="background-color:#000;">
 <h2> This is test example and half caption is hiding in left side on mobile device below <=4 inch screen</h2>
 <h6>   <a href="seo-sem-ppc.php" class="btn-default btn-sm">More</a> </h6>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#kc1" data-slide="prev">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
 </a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#kc1" data-slide="next">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
 </a> 
 </div>

 <style>
 <!-- carousel css-->
 .btn-clear {
 color: #FFF;
 border-color: #FFF;
 border-width: 2px;
 margin-right: 15px;
 }
 btn-clear:hover {
 color: #000;
 background-color: #6699CC;
 }
 #kc1
 {
 border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px; /* slider.css ln-17*/
 /* added by kk */
 overflow: hidden;
 /* added by kk */
 margin-top: 1px;
 min-height: 300px;
 min-width: 100%;
 }
 #kc1 img {
 min-height: 300px;
 min-width: 100%;       
 }
 #kc1 > .carousel-indicators > li {
 border-radius: 2px;
 min-width: 2px;
 background-color:#D4FF00;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin-right: 1px;;
 margin-left: 1px;;
 }
 #kc1 > .carousel-indicators > .active {
 background-color:#2AFF00;
 }
 #kc1 .carousel-caption {
 color: blue;   
 right: 50%;
 text-align: center;
 background:#fff;   
 left: auto;
 top:12%;
 bottom: initial;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 transform:translateX(50%);
 color:#FFF;
 max-width: 1200px; 
 }
 .item {
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 -webkit-
 }
 </style>
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fv02jbm7/) for clarification

Comment: Did you figure out your situation? Did you bother to go to the mentioned code in my answer to fix the problem you had?

Answer (score 0):

The caption in a carousel is actually being controlled in the site.css file under this part:

```
/* Hide/rearrange for smaller screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  /* Hide captions */
  .carousel-caption {
     display: none
  }
```

}